# How to support chinese/japanese etc language in QT-TextField

Tags: qt

I am getting an empty string when inputing the QT-TestFiled  with Chinese or Japanese language.

Getting the correct display for English language.

Comment: How do you input strings?

Answer (score -1):

The **QT TextField** work with **Chinese and Japanese characters**. So that's not because of the TextField. Maybe probably do something with your TextField which remove the text.
I will give you a `Qt Quick Control 2` code I tested with chinese characters.

.pro

```
QT += qml quick

CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
        }

        Page {
            Label {
                text: qsTr("Second page")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Page1Form {
    button1.onClicked: {
        console.log("Button Pressed. Entered text: " + textField1.text);
        label.text = textField1.text
    }
}
```

Page1From.ui.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

Item {
    property alias textField1: textField1
    property alias button1: button1
    property alias label: label

    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2
        rows: 2

        TextField {
            id: textField1
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            placeholderText: qsTr("Text Field")
        }

        Button {
            id: button1
            text: qsTr("Press Me")
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }

        Label {
            id: label
            width: 213
            height: 54
            Layout.columnSpan: 2
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

qtquickcontrols2.conf

```
; This file can be edited to change the style of the application
; See Styling Qt Quick Controls 2 in the documentation for details:
; http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html

[Controls]
Style=Material

[Universal]
Theme=Dark
;Accent=Steel

[Material]
Theme=Dark
;Accent=BlueGrey
;Primary=BlueGray
```

Comment: @DebashishSamantaray you are welcome :) can you validate my answer plz ? ^^

Comment: I have added the particular  xxx.ttf file in qt font  which is under lib it is working fine  now.